# What is the angle brackets part is called in C# e.g. SomeMethodName<ISomething>()

Tags: c#, terminology

Given the following in C#:

```
public Complex SomeMethodName<ISomething>(int x, int y, ....)
```

we can describe each part as follows :

```
public : accessor specifier
Complex : the resut of the function
SomeMethodName : Method Name
<ISomething> : ???
(int x, int y, ....) : parameter list
```

My question is what is the name for `<ISomething>` Part?

PS : I know the name for angle brackets, but what does that part signify? the generiticisim of the method?

**Update** : for example 
we would read

```
public Complex SomeMethodName(int x, int y, ....)
```

as public method SomeMethodName returning Complex as result and taking parameters int x, int y, ...

Should we read

```
public Complex SomeMethodName<ISomething>(int x, int y, ....)
```

as public method SomeMethodName of generic type ISomething returning Complex as result and taking parameters int x, int y, ... ?

Comment: maybe `generic argument list`?

Comment: `<ISomething>` => this is called generic type parameter. See [Generics in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : updated the question,

Comment: @Arjang You can interpret the method reading as this: "A public generic SomeMethodName method with return type 'Complex' and type parameter 'ISomething' which takes 'x' & 'y' as integer argument/parameter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Generic Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) of [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

Comment: Thank you , can you please look at my updated question?

Comment: @Arjang Maybe "A generic method `SomeMethodName` method with `ISomething` generic type parameter that take `x` & `y` as parameters and return a `Complex` value as result.".

But I think @Tetsuya Yamamoto 's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what is the name for  Part?

is type parameter for generic method.

For example:

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}
```

The above defined method is called with  replaced with desired type:

```
public static void TestSwap()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    Swap<int>(ref a, ref b);
    System.Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);
}
```

So in the above `Swap<int>` here we are passing type parameter **int**

This [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) explains about generic methods.

Answer (score -3):

Template type.
Template typename.
Template parameter.
Template argument.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure about so many down votes. The question was, what the angular bracket part was called. It is generally called template parameter, template argument, etc. Nothing really to elaborate.

Comment: Dude, the Generic Type has nothing to do with a template. Please delete your post you're affecting 1 of my rep points.

Comment: You do understand the terms "generics" and "templates" are generally synonymous? (The generic collections started from C++ templates / STL.)

Comment: Yes, I do. However your archaic answer is not upvoted. When talking.net please refer to templates in the T4 type of sense.